# How to save the layout design builded by drag and drop UI to the options value of <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var counter = 1;
var rotat = 5;
var checkDropZone,
  $clone,
  cloneId,
  cloneOff,
  wardInfo,
  contentValue,
  childAttr,
  cloneChildAttrId,
  layoutData,
  optText,
  optValue;

var offset, xPos, yPos;

$(document).ready(function() {

  var $draggable = $('.list-zone-1, .list-zone-2, .list-zone-3, .list-zone-4, .list-zone-5, .list-zone-6, .list-zone-7, .zone-6, .zone-7, .zone-8');
  wardInfo = '<div class="form-group "><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-center"><label class="control-label input"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="addValue" placeholder="Enter Value" id="addValue" /></label></div><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center"><button class=" btntest btn green btn-sm assignedGroup" type="button" data-target-id="addValue">ADD</button><button class="btnCancel btn red btn-sm assignedGroup" type="button" data-target-id="CancelValue" data-dismiss="close">CANCEL</button></div></div>';

  $('.select2me').on('change', function() {
    optText = $('.select2me option:selected').text();
    optValue = $('.select2me option:selected').val();
    checkDropZone = $('.drop-zone').html();

    /*Check whether selected option have the value
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: optValue,
        contentType: 'application/JSON; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("Result: " + result);
            $('.drop-zone').html(result);
        }
    });*/

    if (checkDropZone !== '') {
      console.log('Drop Zone is not Empty, Pls Clean the Drop Zone!');
      confirm("Are you sure to Empty the Drop Zone!!");
      layoutReset();
    } else {
      console.log('Drop Zone is Empty, Pls make some Design..');

      $draggable.draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: '-webkit-grab',

        drag: function(e) {
          offset = $(this).offset();
          xPos = offset.left;
          yPos = offset.top;
          console.log("Offset " + offset + ", Xpos: " + xPos + ", " + "Ypos : " + yPos);
        },
        tolerance: 'fit',
        revert: 'invalid',
        start: function(event, ui) {
          ui.helper.data('dropped', true);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          console.log('stop: dropped=' + ui.helper.data('dropped'));
        }
      });


      $(".drop-zone").droppable({
        accept: $draggable,
        cursor: 'move',
        // zIndex: '999',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.data('dropped', true); //Check to see if this draggable has been dropped
            $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            console.log($clone);

            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
              if (e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
                $clone.remove();
              }
            });

            //Creating Attributes to the Cloned Element
            $clone.attr({
              'id': 'clonedElement' + counter,
              'data-toggle': 'popover',
              'position': 'absolute',
              'data-patient_name': "",
              'data-ipNo': "",
              'data-inDate': "",
              'data-bedStatus': ""
            });

            cloneId = $clone.attr('id');
            // alert('Clone Id : ' +cloneId );
            $clone.click(function() {
              $(this).each(function(e) {
                console.log($(e.target));
              });
            });


            childAttr = $clone.children().attr('class');
            cloneChildAttrId = $clone.children().attr('id', 'list-zone-' + counter);
            cloneChildAttrId = cloneChildAttrId.attr('id');

            if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
              $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                containment: '.drop-zone',
                cursor: 'move',
                zIndex: '999',
                revert: 'true'
              }));

              //Positioning the Cloned Element in the drop-zone.

              var pos = eval($(ui.helper).offset());
              console.log(pos);
              var draggableOffset = ui.helper.offset();
              console.log(draggableOffset);
              droppableOffset = $(this).offset();
              console.log(droppableOffset);
              left = (draggableOffset.left - droppableOffset.left) + 15 + 'px';
              console.log("Left:" + left);
              thisTop = (draggableOffset.top - droppableOffset.top) + 25 + 'px';
              console.log("Top: " + thisTop);


              cloneOff = $clone.offset().left;
              console.log("Offset Value : " + cloneOff);

              if ($clone.hasClass('zone-6') || $clone.hasClass('zone-7') || $clone.hasClass('zone-8')) {
                $clone.css({
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "left": left,
                  "top": thisTop
                    // "background-color": "#fff",
                    // "border": "1px solid #444" 
                });
              } else {
                $clone.css({
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "left": left,
                  "top": thisTop,
                  "background-color": "#fff",
                  "border": "1px solid #bbb"
                });
              }

              if ($clone.hasClass('list-zone-1') || $clone.hasClass('list-zone-2') || $clone.hasClass('list-zone-3')) {
                $clone.resizable({
                  helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                  containment: '.drop-zone',
                  maxHeight: $('.drop-zone').height(),
                  maxWidth: $('.drop-zone').width(),
                  //handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw, n, s, w, e',
                  handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
                  aspectRadio: false
                });
              }

              //Auto increment to generate dynamic id for cloned object
              counter++;

              //Creating the Popover to bind the value to Cloned Element.
              $clone.on('click', function() {

                // if ($(this).hasClass('list-zone-1') || $(this).hasClass('list-zone-2') || $(this).hasClass('list-zone-3') || $(this).hasClass('zone-6') || $(this).hasClass('zone-7') || $(this).hasClass('zone-8')) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('list-zone-1') || $(this).hasClass('list-zone-2') || $(this).hasClass('list-zone-3')) {
                  return;
                } else {
                  $('#' + cloneId).each(function(event) {
                    console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
                  });

                  $('#' + cloneId).popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: 'Enter Ward No <button type="button" id="close" class="close" data-dismiss="popover">&times;</button>',
                    content: wardInfo
                  });

                  $(document).on('click', '.popover .close', function() {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
                  });
                }
              });
            } //Ending of if                       
          } //Ending of drop property
      }); //Ending of Droppable method

      $(document).on('click', '.btntest', function() {
        contentValue = $('#addValue').val();
        displayDialogValue(contentValue);
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.btnCancel', function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
      });
    }
  });

  $('.drop-zone').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && !$('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    });
  });
});

function displayDialogValue(value) {
  if (!value == "" || !value == undefined || !value == null) {
    var dataVal = $clone.attr('data-Bed_no', value);

    if ($clone.hasClass('list-zone-6') || $clone.hasClass('list-zone-7')) {
      $('<p id="elVal"></p>').insertAfter('#' + cloneChildAttrId).append(value).css({
        'margin-top': '50px',
        'text-align': 'center'
      });
    } else {
      $('<p id="elVal"></p>').insertAfter('#' + cloneChildAttrId).append(value).css({
        'margin-top': '25px',
        'text-align': 'center'
      });
    }
    return value;
  } else {
    alert("Pls enter the data..");
  }
}

// function saveLayout(){
//     alert('Entered into Function.');
//     var saveEle = [$clone.attr('id')];
//     $clone.attr('id');
//     $clone.val();


// }

function saveLayout() {

  layoutData = $('.drop-zone').html()
    //var savedData = localStorage.setItem('data', layoutData)
  console.log("Data after Stringify: " + layoutData);
  var savedData = localStorage.setItem('data', layoutData);

  debugger;
  var idarr = [];
  $clone.each(function() {
    //idarr.push($clone.attr('id'));
    idarr.push(layoutData);
  });
  var savedData = localStorage.setItem('data', idarr)

  $.each(idarr, function(index, value) {
    console.log("Cloned Ids : " + value);
  });

  if (optText === $('.select2me option:selected').text()) {
    alert("Optional Text Value is equalent to the option text selected: " + optText);
    assignLayout(optValue, layoutData);
    //var savedData = localStorage.setItem('data', layoutData);
    //getLayout(optValue, data);
  }
}

function viewLayout() {
  assignLayout(optValue, layoutData);
}

function assignLayout(data, value) {
  var encodeData = encodeURIComponent(data);
  console.log("Option Value: " + encodeData);

  var encodeValue = encodeURIComponent(value);
  console.log("Option Data Encoded : " + encodeValue);

  var url = 'wardView.html?data=' + encodeData + '&value=' + encodeValue;
  console.log(url);
  window.location.replace(url);

  /*$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: {
          data,
          value
      },
      contentType: 'application/JSON; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(result) {

          alert("Result: " + result);
      }
  });*/
}

//Display the stored design
function getLayout(value, data) {
  alert('Value: ' + value + " & " + 'Data : ' + data);
  $('#resultDiv').html(localStorage.getItem('value', 'data'));
  $('#resultDiv').css({
    'margin-bottom': '50px',
    'background': '#fff',
    'box-shadow': '0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)'
  });
}

//Resetting the Design Layout
function layoutReset() {
  $('.drop-zone').empty();
  return;
}
```

```css
.col-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
.wardLayoutSection {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 650px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.portlet {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.portlet.light {
  padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#wardSubmitBtn,
#wardClearBtn,
#wardViewBtn {
  width: 100px;
}
.drop-zone,
.zoneContents {
  border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  min-height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.zoneContents {
  /*padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 45px;*/
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  background: #ccc;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.tool-wrapper {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.list-zone-1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.list-zone-4,
.list-zone-5 {
  /*.zone-2,
.zone-3 {*/
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.list-zone-6,
.list-zone-7 {
  /*.zone-4,
.zone-5 {*/
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.zone-6 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  /*border:1px solid #555555;*/
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.zone-7 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  /*border:1px solid #555555;*/
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.zone-8 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  /*border:1px solid #555555;*/
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.tool-wrapper img {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.list-zone-2 {
  /*.zone_curve1 {*/
  width: 25px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
/*.zone_curve2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 45px;
  border:1px solid #444;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 0px!important;
  border-radius: 50px 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}*/

.list-zone-3 {
  /*.zone_curve2 {*/
  width: 25px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px !important;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
  /*cursor: move;*/
}
.list-zone-4 {
  /*.zone-2 {*/
  background: url('../img/bed_1_final.png') no-repeat #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.list-zone-5 {
  /*.zone-3 {*/
  background: url('../img/bed_2_final.png') no-repeat #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.list-zone-6 {
  /*.zone-4 {*/
  background: url('../img/bed_4_final.png') no-repeat #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.list-zone-7 {
  /*.zone-5 {*/
  background: url('../img/bed_3_final.png') no-repeat #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.zone-6 {
  background: url('../img/hospital-reception.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.zone-7 {
  background: url('../img/water-tap-with-drop.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.zone-8 {
  background: url('../img/restRoom_1.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.list-zone-1,
.list-zone-2,
.list-zone-3 {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.list-zone-4,
.list-zone-5,
.list-zone-6,
.list-zone-7,
.zone-6,
.zone-7,
.zone-8 {
  cursor: move;
}
/*.drop-zone img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 30px;
    max-width: 10%;
}*/

.tool-wrapper .list-group-item {
  padding: 2px 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.tool-wrapper span {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#zone_direction {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  max-width: 10%;
}
#result_section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
/*---- Input Controls for Manipulation ----*/

#main_layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 30px;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
}
#curve_title_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  right: 30px;
}
#curve_title_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  right: 30px;
}
#bed_title_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  right: 35px;
}
#bed_title_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 35px;
}
#bed_title_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 302px;
  right: 35px;
}
#bed_title_4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  right: 35px;
}
/*------- Drop Zone Styles ---------*/

.drop-zone .list-zone-1:hover,
.drop-zone .list-group-item:active,
/*.drop-zone .zone_curve1:hover,
.drop-zone .zone-curve1:active*/

{
  outline: 2px dashed rgba(222, 60, 80, .9);
}
.drop-zone .zone_curve2:hover,
.drop-zone .zone_curve2:active {
  outline: 2px dashed rgba(222, 60, 80, .9);
}
.ui-resizable-helper {
  border: 2px solid #35aa47;
}
.activeWard-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #35aa47;
}
.zone-2 img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
/*#draggable { 
   width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  border:1px solid #555555;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}*/

img#draggable {
  max-width: 100px;
}
.tool-title {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.tool-title span {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}
.pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  background: darkslategray;
  padding: 15px 5px 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 350px;
}
#dialog {
  position: element(#target);
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background: #3a9893;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 10px;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-widget .ui-widget-content {
  padding: 0;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  border: none;
}
/*.tooltip {
    background-color: #73AD21;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}*/

.layoutBtns {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  border-top: transparent;
}
/*.popover {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}*/

.popover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)!important;
}
.popover-title {
  background-color: #67809f;
  color: #fff;
}
.btntest {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.popover-content {
  padding: 10px 15px 25px;
}
/*--- Styling the tooltip --*/

.zone-6 + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pull-right">Select any one from Dropdown: </h4>
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient Name"> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="selectward" class="select2me form-control">
          <option value="">--Select Ward--</option>
          <option value="1">Ward1</option>
          <option value="2">Ward2</option>
          <option value="3">Ward3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button type="button" id="wardSubmitBtn" class="btn green" onclick="saveLayout();">SAVE</button>
      <button type="button" id="wardViewBtn" class="btn blue" onclick="viewLayout();">VIEW</button>
      <button type="button" id="wardClearBtn" class="btn red" onclick="layoutReset();">CLEAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Ward Design Canvas Layout -->
<div class="row wardDesignWrapper">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="zoneContents" id="zoneContents">
      <div class="tool-title text-center">
        <span class="wardLayout">Tools</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tool-wrapper">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-1 col-center">
              <div class="zone-1" id="zone-1"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-2 col-center">
              <div class="zone_curve1" id="zone_curve1">
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-3 col-center">
              <div class="zone_curve2" id="zone_curve2">
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-4 col-center">
              <div class="zone-2" id="zone-2"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-5 col-center">
              <div class="zone-3" id="zone-3"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-6 col-center">
              <div class="zone-4" id="zone-4"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
            <div class="list-zone-7 col-center">
              <div class="zone-5" id="zone-5"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="otherContents">
          <div class="tool-title text-center">
            <span class="wardLayout">Others</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tool-wrapper">
            <div class="zone-6 col-center" id="nurseDesk" draggable="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Nurse Desk"></div>
            <div class="zone-7 col-center" id="drnWater" draggable="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Drinking Water"></div>
            <div class="zone-8 col-center" id="restRoom" draggable="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Rest Room"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Zone Contents ends here -->
      </div>
      <!-- Col-1 Ending here -->
      <div class="col-md-11" id="drop-layout">
        <form role="form" id="layoutForm" action="" method="">
          <div class="drop-zone"></div>
          <img class="img-responsive" id="zone_direction" src="img/zone_direction.png" alt="Zone Direction">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section id="result_section">
      <div class="resultDiv" id="resultDiv"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have a Dropdown html element to allow the user to select and design the layout using Drag snd Drop Api using jQuery Ui. Then the design should save to the option selected, so that user can select and view the layout saved whenever the option select.

I can able to drag and drop the html elements and makes the clone to build the layout. But I need to assign or save the layout builded to the option selected in the dropdown.

I have tried to save the layout using Localstorage, but I can't able to save the layout design to particular option.

The screenshot has been attached here, Pls have a look, if I'm not clear on the above points.
[image: Snapshot of Layout Builder]

Comment: Show the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: I have edited my post, pls check.. @fsacer

Comment: I have fixed the issue, if anyone think this useful, pls comment I will share the  coding here.. Thanks..